# .NET 8 Blazor web application Microsoft identity controller problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I have a Blazor web application using Microsoft identity for authentication. I have it working with `[Authorize]` attribute on the frontend pages to only allow signed in users to navigate to certain pages. Though I am having issues when trying to add authentication to the backend controllers for example:

App.Employee.Overview.razor.cs

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var state = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    user = state.User;

    if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Employees = (await EmployeeDataService.GetAllEmployees()).ToList();
    }
}
```

I have this `OnInitializedAsync` call to the `GetAllEmployees` controller in my backend via a service class. The page itself that this `OnInititializedAsync` resides is is authenticated properly using the `[Authorize]` and the call to the endpoint is only being activated `user.Identity.IsAuthenticated` implying the user is correctly logged in and authenticated.

Though this is the case I get the following error in the backend:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
> Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
> DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
> dotnet.native.8.0.0.dytb5xdnry.js:8
> invoke-js.ts:176 info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.IEmployeeDataService.LogicalHandler[100]
>
> Start processing HTTP request GET https://localhost:7039/api/employee
> invoke-js.ts:176 info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.IEmployeeDataService.ClientHandler[100]
> Sending HTTP request GET https://localhost:7039/api/employee
> api/employee:1
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()
> invoke-js.ts:176 info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.IEmployeeDataService.ClientHandler[101]
> Received HTTP response headers after 41.6ms - 401
> invoke-js.ts:176 info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.IEmployeeDataService.LogicalHandler[101]
> End processing HTTP request after 379.4ms - 401
> blazor.webassembly.js:1
> crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

Controller endpoint code causing issue:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public EmployeeController(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
        _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult GetAllEmployees()
    {
        return Ok(_employeeRepository.GetAllEmployees());
    }
}
```

Api.Program.cs code:

```
using CompetencyApp.Api.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => {
    options.UseSqlServer(
        builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]);
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<ICountryRepository, CountryRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmployeeRepository, EmployeeRepository>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Open", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapIdentityApi<IdentityUser>();
app.UseCors("Open");

app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
app.Run();
```

App.Program.cs:

```
using CompetencyApp.App;
using CompetencyApp.App.Services;
using Blazored.LocalStorage;
using Blazored.SessionStorage;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IEmployeeDataService, EmployeeDataService>(client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)).AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<ICountryDataService, CountryDataService>(client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)).AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<ApplicationState>();

builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
});

builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredSessionStorage();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

Note: if I take the `[Authorize]` attribute out of the controller, it works, but that is not what I want to do. I want only authorized user to be able to call that endpoint.

Comment: You should use `Cookie Authentication`, then use `Http.DefaultRequestHeaders
            .Add("Cookie", ".AspNetCore.Cookies=" + authToken);
           
            var url = UriHelper.ToAbsoluteUri("/api/Employee/GetAllEmployees");` to call the controller.

Comment: Here is the good tutorial ([A Demonstration of Simple Server-side Blazor Cookie Authentication](https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/36)) for you.

Comment: @JasonPan I have been using the code from the Visual Studio Microsoft Identity Login template for Blazor NET 8 web app. and the only login code is as follows:
 `<Authorized>
        <button class="nav-link btn btn-link" @onclick="BeginLogout">Logout</button>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="authentication/login">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
@code {
    private async Task BeginSignOut(MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        await SignOutManager.SetSignOutState();
        Navigation.NavigateTo("authentication/logout");
    }
}`